# passing parameter to existing exe generated from launch4j

Tags: launch4j

I was successful in building a new program.exe file from a jar and passing in an -Dargs from the xml to pass an argument into java.

However, my situation is that I cannot replace the existing program.exe with a new program.exe

Is there a way to pass in -Dargs to the already existing program.exe?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, explained in the [Docs](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html) at `Additional JVM options at runtime`